# pandas dataframe, how to get average of a value over a certain index

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
Age Gender  
20   Male  
10   Male  
18   Female  
15   Male  
19   Female  
17   Female
```

How can I can a DataFrame like:

```
Age  Gender  
15   Male  
18   Female
```

The age in the new DataFrame is the average age of the old DataFrame with corresponding Gender respectively.

Comment: `df.groupby('Gender', as_index=False).Age.mean()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In [51]: df.groupby('Gender', as_index=False).Age.mean()
Out[51]:
   Gender  Age
0  Female   18
1    Male   15
```

> How can I make the result DataFrame a Series with Gender as
>   keys/index?

```
In [61]: s = df.groupby('Gender').Age.mean()

In [62]: s
Out[62]:
Gender
Female    18
Male      15
Name: Age, dtype: int64

In [63]: type(s)
Out[63]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: How can I make the result DataFrame a Series with Gender as keys/index?

Comment: Nevermind, it is already a Series. I printed out the type and I got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.

Comment: `as_index` parameter let you control whether the "grouping" column(s) will go to the inde or not...