# how to find mean of a column based upon its group in pandas

Tags: pandas, mean

I'm using pandas and using a data set that has a column of class having values 1, 2 and 3 and have a column of age that has a variety of values.

Now I want to find the average/mean of the age depending upon which class they belong to ie class 1, 2 or 3. The data set has 900 rows and 9 columns in it. How can I do it ??

Comment: Please write in a correct format and English next time.

Comment: Plus try to do it yourself, do not expect people to do your work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas dataframe, how to get average of a value over a certain index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504553/pandas-dataframe-how-to-get-average-of-a-value-over-a-certain-index)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html has already an example of this.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi tysm for your insights .Really mature replies as expected .

Comment: @AjayAlex I haven't decided the policies, take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Plus it is not a question of how mature people are, but how you are supposed to ask questions on SO.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi again Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are really welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One possible solution is,**

```
df.loc[df['class'] == 1, 'age'].mean()
```

Where `df['class']` can be whatever columns that you want `==` to whatever value that you want in the class column

Hope this answers your question.